# GUI Organization 5th BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I don't understand how I can have two classes displayed once I have already used up one of the corners (NORTH, EAST, WEST, SOUTH), how can I add a fifth class by using border layout? as you can see in the build buttons area, I need to be able to have two classes in the are, I don't care where the tastybois class goes I just need to be able to have 5 things displayed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class IkeaRun extends JFrame{
private IkeaMainDish Dish;
private Drinks drinks;
private SideDish Side;
private IkeaGreetings greeting;
private TastyBois tastybois;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JButton calcButton;
private JButton exitButton;
private final double taxRate = 0.06;
public IkeaRun(){
    setTitle("ORDER");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    greeting = new IkeaGreetings();
    Dish = new IkeaMainDish();
    drinks = new Drinks();
    Side = new SideDish();
    tastybois = new TastyBois();
    buildButtons();
    add(greeting, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(Dish, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(drinks, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(Side, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(tastybois, BorderLayout.EAST);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

}
private void buildButtons(){
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        calcButton = new JButton("Order");
        exitButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());
        mainPanel.add(calcButton);
        mainPanel.add(exitButton);
 }
 private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          double subtotal = 0.0;
          double tax = 0.0;;
          double total = 0.0;
         subtotal = Dish.getDishPrice() + 
                    drinks.getDrinkPrice() +
                    Side.getSidePrice();
         tax = subtotal * taxRate;
         total = subtotal + tax;
         DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Subtotal: $" + dollar.format(subtotal) + "\n" + "Tax: $" + dollar.format(tax) + "\n" + "Total: $" + dollar.format(total));
      }
      }
 private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          System.exit(0);
      }
   }
```

}

Comment: Show code and explain what you're trying to see...

Comment: Don't forget about `CENTER`.

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with a second JPanel so you have a hierarchy such your main JPanel (called container here) holds 5 other JPanels trough BorderLayout, on each sub-panel you set a new LayoutManager and add the components to it.